# Fire some code when dismissing SwiftUI modal

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a modal built with SwitftUI which has a `TextField` with `onCommit:` code which saves user input from `@State` variable to file when user taps "return" on keyboard.

However, if user types something inside `TextField` and then dismisses the modal without pressing "return", the `onCommit:` code doesn't fire and user input stays unsaved. How do I fire some code accessing inner variable of my modal View when it is dismissed?

Comment: If you want help with your code you should show it.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

Instead having a private @State var on your modal, make it an internal `@Binding` that you pass into the modal from the call site. This way the modified bound variable is available on both the caller and the modal view.

Answer (score 1):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var dismiss = false
    @State var txt = ""
    @State var store = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        Text("modal").sheet(isPresented: $dismiss, onDismiss: {
            self.store = self.txt
        }) {
            TextField("txt", text: self.$txt) {
                self.store = self.txt
            }.padding().border(Color.red)
        }.onTapGesture {
            self.dismiss.toggle()
        }
            Text(store)
        }
    }
}

struct ContetView_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```